# Enabling Google Sitelinks Search Box?

Tags: seo, search-engine, google-search, schema.org, json-ld

I'm trying to enable Google Sitelinks Search Box.
It's something which allows you to display directly a "search textbox" in Google : https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview

I've added it to the website the 27 July, using the JSON-LD syntax. According to Google, the currently cached version of website is the one of the 6 August (so a long time after deployment), but the search textbox has never appeared in Google.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">   
{     
"@context": "http://schema.org",     
"@type": "WebSite",     
"url": "https://fr.blabla.com/",     
"potentialAction":
{       
"@type": "SearchAction",       
"target": "https://fr.blabla.com/acheter/{search_term_string}?page=1",       
"query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
}   
}   
</script>
```

Sorry, I can't disclose the real URL. On the screenshot, the subdomain and the end of the URL are the real ones, the website is in HTTPS.

The "search engine" URL works fine if I call it directly.
The code is located in the `head` HTML segment of my page (it's not easy to test to move it, the website is a huge e-commerce platform and I can't test anything as I would).

The Google test tool (https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) seems to validate my code: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyYpL.jpg](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=823756Googlesearch.jpg)

I found another website (type "cdiscount" in Google) which use it exactly like me and it looks like to work for them. The only differences I notice is they are not in HTTPS, their subdomain is www and their `<script>` tag is somewhere in the `body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two thing to consider here...

1. It can take Google a while to implement your code. I've seen it take a couple of months.
2. Adding sitelinks in the SERPs is at Google's discretion so having the code in your site is not a guarantee they will show sitelinks for the site.

So I'm afraid it's now a waiting game.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it was an automated process, or almost. I wasn't thinking it could take so long.

Comment: William, could you just please confirm there is nothing more to do for us to request to Google to integrate the feature, we just have to put the json code online (as currently) and they decide if they handle it and when ? My customer want to be sure there is no need to "officially" request it to google, or something. Thanks

Comment: You can't request this from Google direct, you place the code on to your site and leave it up to Google. If they think sitelinks will help the user then they will show it in the SERPs.

Comment: As taken from here: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview - "Search box not displaying? The Sitelinks search box appears only for navigational queries and when relevant for users. Google algorithms use a variety of factors to determine when the search box appears, including the information on the site and different types of navigational queries from Search users."

Comment: I was informed about the second quote, but we didn't figured how much time it takes to google to integrate it, there was nothing regarding this specified on the google official pages. Anyway, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

1. Actually it only takes a few days at the most after you use Fetch as Google to have the site re-crawled.
2. The documentation states that it is at their discretion and may depend on how busy your site is, but mine has been running under a year and isn't busy and they work. (I was surprised since I could not confirm this elsewhere).

A common mistake is not to realize how to check sitelinks, you need to search for the full website name eg **blabla.com** or **blabla** - using **site:blabla.com** won't show the site links.

If you want to see the Search text box as well make sure you only add the code to the home page of your site.